# Ping is slow even when a server has enough bandwidth

Tags: linux, networking, ping

Hello stackoverflow community,
I'd like to get help to understand what causes ping to be slow

(This is copied from Stackoverflow following to an advice I've got there)

### context

- I have two linux servers.

  1. rasberry pi 4

  - kernel is `5.4.0-1042-raspi`

  2. Lenovo n75q tiny gen2

  - kernel is `5.4.0-89-generic`
- They have an identical `/etc/netplan/99_config.yaml` file, and belongs to the same wifi network
- They both are connected with the Internet, and they can retrieve contents from outer wolld. (I mean curl works in both servers)
- Their cpu are not busy, and they have enough mem.

### problem

- When accessing to the second server(Lenovo) via ssh, its response is very laggy. (every single typing is laggy)

  - However, it has better bandwidth than rasberry pi.
  - The only curious fact I've found throw investigation on this is, ping to lenovo is slower than to rasberry pi.
- rasberry pi works/responds very smoothly.

### question

- What can be the reason why lenovo is laggy when accessing to it via ssh?
- (If the reason is the same as the reason why ping is slow, ) how can I address to fix this issue?

#### result of iperf

```
# rasberry pi
[ ID] Interval       Transfer     Bandwidth
[  4] local 192.168.3.13 port 5001 connected with 192.168.3.2 port 52172
[  4]  0.0-12.8 sec   100 MBytes  65.6 Mbits/sec
[  4] local 192.168.3.13 port 5001 connected with 192.168.3.2 port 52248
[  4]  0.0-153.3 sec  1000 MBytes  54.7 Mbits/sec

# lenovo
[ ID] Interval       Transfer     Bandwidth
[  4] local 192.168.3.11 port 5001 connected with 192.168.3.2 port 52163
[  4]  0.0-12.4 sec   100 MBytes  67.6 Mbits/sec
[  4] local 192.168.3.11 port 5001 connected with 192.168.3.2 port 52180
[  4]  0.0-64.8 sec  1000 MBytes   129 Mbits/sec
[  4] local 192.168.3.11 port 5001 connected with 192.168.3.2 port 52312
[  4]  0.0-68.4 sec  1000 MBytes   123 Mbits/sec
```

#### result of speedtest

```
# rasberry pi
$ speedtest
Retrieving speedtest.net configuration...
Testing from Softbank BB ...
Retrieving speedtest.net server list...
Selecting best server based on ping...
Hosted by denpa893 (Tokyo) [4.11 km]: 18.09 ms
Testing download speed................................................................................
Download: 53.25 Mbit/s
Testing upload speed......................................................................................................
Upload: 58.68 Mbit/s

# lenovo
$ speedtest
Retrieving speedtest.net configuration...
Testing from Softbank BB ...
Retrieving speedtest.net server list...
Selecting best server based on ping...
Hosted by NEVERLOSS LLC. (Tokyo) [4.11 km]: 12.093 ms
Testing download speed................................................................................
Download: 189.07 Mbit/s
Testing upload speed......................................................................................................
Upload: 74.77 Mbit/s
```

#### result of ping

```
# rasberry pi
$ ping -s 1000 192.168.3.13
PING 192.168.3.13 (192.168.3.13): 1000 data bytes
1008 bytes from 192.168.3.13: icmp_seq=0 ttl=64 time=79.925 ms
1008 bytes from 192.168.3.13: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=10.203 ms
1008 bytes from 192.168.3.13: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=13.297 ms
1008 bytes from 192.168.3.13: icmp_seq=3 ttl=64 time=9.976 ms
1008 bytes from 192.168.3.13: icmp_seq=4 ttl=64 time=2.932 ms
1008 bytes from 192.168.3.13: icmp_seq=5 ttl=64 time=9.611 ms
1008 bytes from 192.168.3.13: icmp_seq=6 ttl=64 time=2.983 ms
1008 bytes from 192.168.3.13: icmp_seq=7 ttl=64 time=12.698 ms
1008 bytes from 192.168.3.13: icmp_seq=8 ttl=64 time=3.286 ms
1008 bytes from 192.168.3.13: icmp_seq=9 ttl=64 time=3.937 ms
1008 bytes from 192.168.3.13: icmp_seq=10 ttl=64 time=2.689 ms

# lenovo
$ ping -s 1000 192.168.3.11
PING 192.168.3.11 (192.168.3.11): 1000 data bytes
1008 bytes from 192.168.3.11: icmp_seq=0 ttl=64 time=211.042 ms <--- much slower than rasberry pi
1008 bytes from 192.168.3.11: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=26.955 ms
1008 bytes from 192.168.3.11: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=47.657 ms
1008 bytes from 192.168.3.11: icmp_seq=3 ttl=64 time=172.856 ms
1008 bytes from 192.168.3.11: icmp_seq=4 ttl=64 time=194.496 ms
1008 bytes from 192.168.3.11: icmp_seq=5 ttl=64 time=216.379 ms
1008 bytes from 192.168.3.11: icmp_seq=6 ttl=64 time=134.123 ms
1008 bytes from 192.168.3.11: icmp_seq=7 ttl=64 time=155.828 ms
```

#### result of traceroute

```
# rasberry pi
$ traceroute 192.168.3.11
traceroute to 192.168.3.11 (192.168.3.11), 64 hops max, 52 byte packets
 1  ${rasberry pi} (192.168.3.11)  4.122 ms  2.568 ms  2.109 ms

# lenovo
$ traceroute 192.168.3.13
traceroute to 192.168.3.13 (192.168.3.13), 64 hops max, 52 byte packets
 1  * ${lenovo} (192.168.3.13)  105.194 ms  3.069 ms
```

#### result of top

```
# rasberry pi
top - 04:03:38 up  3:30,  1 user,  load average: 0.00, 0.00, 0.00
Tasks: 166 total,   1 running, 165 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
%Cpu(s):  0.2 us,  0.2 sy,  0.0 ni, 99.7 id,  0.0 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.0 si,  0.0 st
MiB Mem :   7811.3 total,   6909.1 free,    284.0 used,    618.2 buff/cache
MiB Swap:      0.0 total,      0.0 free,      0.0 used.   7394.4 avail Mem

# lenovo
top - 04:03:54 up  1:45,  1 user,  load average: 0.07, 0.02, 0.00
Tasks: 197 total,   1 running, 196 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
%Cpu(s):  0.0 us,  0.5 sy,  0.0 ni, 99.5 id,  0.0 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.0 si,  0.0 st
MiB Mem :  31587.8 total,  30665.4 free,    426.2 used,    496.3 buff/cache
MiB Swap:      0.0 total,      0.0 free,      0.0 used.  30758.7 avail Mem
```

Comment: What's your MTU? See `ip link`. WiFi MTUs must be 1492, not 1500.

Comment: Cross-posted: https://stackoverflow.com/q/69763543/4424636. Please delete your question on SO, if you wish to post here. See [Is cross-posting a question on multiple Stack Exchange sites permitted if the question is on-topic for each site?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068/280335)

Comment: @Greenonline    Thanks, I’ve deleted one in stackoverflow

Comment: @waltinator  `wlp2s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500`. let me observe what will happen if it's set as 1492

Comment: hmm, chaging mtu to 1492 doesn't fix this issue.

btw, I've noticed that this interface has `noqueue` as one property, and rasberry pi's interface doesn't have it but has `mq`


So, I've put a wifi dongle on Lenove server for testing purpose, then it resolved the issue... (its network interface has `mq`. ). It's not laggy now.

Comment: If `iw dev wlan0 get power_save` returns on, then set it off with `iw dev wlan0 set power_save off` and retry.

Comment: @Bib What a magic... this fixed the issue on the original network interface..

Comment: I'll set it to answer then...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `iw dev wlan0 get power_save` returns on, then set it off with `iw dev wlan0 set power_save off` and retry. I have no idea though how to set it as default, since at each reboot, it will be back to power save mode.

Comment: thank you @Bib!